# Core Data template app generates errors on save

Tags: macos, core-data

While evaluating Core Data for a macOS app, I get errors logged to the console when the document is saved:

```
[logging-persist] cannot open file at line 39930 of [02c344acea]
[logging-persist] os_unix.c:39930: (0) openDirectory(/Users/seanrich/Desktop) - Undefined error: 0
```

The data is saved properly and there's no other indication of an issue, but that error is concerning.

This [sample project](https://github.com/seanmrich/CoreDataSaveTest) demonstrates the issue. It's minimally changed from a template project (selecting SwiftUI as the interface, Core Data checked). There's a single entity, `Item`, with a single attribute, `name`. I added a minimal interface to add items into the `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [.byName]) var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                Button("New") {
                    let item = Item(context: moc)
                    item.name = name
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            VStack {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.name ?? "No name")
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

The `NSPersistentDocument` subclass is unchanged from the template:

EDIT: I added a line to explicitly load the `managedObjectModel` or the SwiftUI view tries to fetch an entity that isn't there yet:

```swift
class Document: NSPersistentDocument {
    override class var autosavesInPlace: Bool { true }

    override func makeWindowControllers() {
        _ = managedObjectModel
        let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext!)

        // Create the window and set the content view.
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.center()
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        let windowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
        self.addWindowController(windowController)
    }
}
```

I thought it might be a permissions issue, but the sandbox is set to give read/write access to user-selected files. Couldn't find any mention of this issue anywhere which is surprising since it seems to be default behavior. Makes me think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't know exactly that that message means, but your sample project has **lots** of Core Data errors before it gets to that point. I'd focus on fixing those first, because this specific error may be a side effect of the various other problems the app complains about.

Comment: @TomHarrington - what errors are you getting? The ones I mentioned in the post are the only errors I get.

Comment: These: https://gist.github.com/atomicbird/9c4177ad00cb783da14db6b72f3ac296

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue @TomHarrington had (thanks for pointing it out!), and it seems the `@FetchRequest` was being executed before the managed object model had loaded the entity. By referencing the model before loading the SwiftUI view, the sample project should better demonstrate the original issue.